# is possible to swap two elements by css?

Tags: html, css

I need to swap two elements by using css. My html is here:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="Div2">
        <img src="Div2.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="Div1">
        <img src="Div1.jpg">
    </div>
</div>
```

and my css is here:

```
.container{width:50%; margin:auto;}
.div2{float:left;width:100%;}
.div1{float:left;width:100%;}
```

is there any way how to put Div1 on the position of Div2 only with css without changing html?

Comment: Yes, but not easily. Look into flexbox and the "order" property.

Comment: Your CSS won't do anything to the child divs since your selectors don't match the classes assigned (they're case sensitive).

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol I don't think flexbox should be used. It doesn't support major browers fully.
http://caniuse.com/flexbox

Comment: @andershagbard: Hence "not easily".

Answer (score -1):

Float `.div2` to the right, and `.div1` to the left:

```
.div2{ float:right; }
.div1{ float:left; }
```

You'll also have to remove the `width: 100%;` if you're attempting to stack them side by side.

Also, classes are case-senstive.  In your example code, your div classes are `.Div1` and `.Div2`, make sure to use all lowercase classes to match the definitions:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="div2">
        <img src="Div2.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="div1">
        <img src="Div1.jpg">
    </div>
</div>
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/dph8t/

Comment: Why are you floating the elements if your goal is to stack them?

Comment: He didn't remove `width:100%`. Also I think he might mean swap them such that there is no gap in the middle you get with floating to the right, but I'm just speculating.

Comment: @user3016214 - Here is your example with swapped positions.  You can use absolute positioning to force the order of the blocks.  I wouldn't consider it more efficient then just switching the markup order, but it works: http://jsfiddle.net/daeqg/1/